# Distributed random on cluster

Tags: c++, random, distributed

I need a deterministic random number generator that maintains some sort of distribution (e.g. uniform or normal) that works over a cluster.

Boost::Random fulfils most of these requirements. Is there any way I can use it in a cluster while maintaining the distribution?

If there was an efficent way to advance the the number generator this would be ideal, however I cant find such a function. Obviously I can call the function repeatedly in a loop, but I'll need to do this several thousand times(possibly a lot more) on each node.

Any recommendation on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something obvious here, but couldn't you just give each cluster's RNG a different (pseudo)randomly chosen seed? I think that would give you a uniform distribution over all clusters.

An alternative would be to have all random numbers dispensed from a single computer that acts as an RNG server, but that would probably be slow.

Comment: I can't think of any common random distributions for which each node having its own RNG wouldn't work.  It seems like the OP may just be overthinking the problem.  Now, if they wanted something more strange like a Poisson Disc distribution, then all bits are off.

Comment: You are missing something obvious.  Suppose you have two machines in your cluster and by a stroke of bad luck, both machines start with the same seed.  Your combined RNG is now not so random.  Now, suppose the seeds are off by one or three - errors are still there, but it's not as obvious unless you happen to notice that the numbers generated by the first machine happens to be the same sequence as that generated by the second machine, shifted by one or three.

Comment: @kfmfe04: I didn't miss that, though. Randomness entails the possibility of repeating sequences every once in a while. Plus, if you know the seeds, then the pattern is predictable, which has the same effect whether two of the seeds are the same or not.

Comment: Well, the actual problem is, if you are using the same PRNG, the two streams have correlation one (they are exactly the same), after shifting for a fixed number of positions depending on the seed picked.  As long as the user is aware of this weakness and finds it acceptable (it may not be, for applications like Monte Carlo simulations or cryptography), then this solution would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how robust you need your PRNG to be, you may need to tread carefully here; there are definitely pitfalls in using multiple PRNGs.

In particular, there are experts in statistics who specialize in researching parallel algorithms for PRNG.

To get started thinking about some of those issues, you may want to look at a paper like [this](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~mascagni/papers/RICP23.pdf).

Like all problems, I recommend that you shoot for getting it right, first, and then getting it to run quickly.